# pig , count array_element

Tags: arrays, count, apache-pig, element

I have data like below

```
1,1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|2|2|3|3|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|3,2016-17-08
2,1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1,2016-07-10
3,1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1,2017-06-04
```

I want to count number of 1's in each array so that I can determine which product has highest number of 1's

```
grunt> a= load 'product_details.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (product_id :int, event_id:chararray, date:chararray);
```

I don't understand how should I count elements in array?

Comment: I would read each one as a string, tokenize by breaking at pipes, and count the ones that way.

Comment: I did the tokenize as below :
grunt> b = foreach a generate product_id , event_id , date ,BagToString(TOKENIZE(event_id,'|'),',');

it generate output as:
(1,1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|2|2|3|3|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|3,2016-17-08,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3)
(2,1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1,2016-07-10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
......

now how will count function work to count nmber of 1's , since count function works only with bag.

Comment: I don't know what that bag stuff is about.  I do know how to tokenize a String.  Can you leave PIG out of it and just do it in Java to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokenize the letters in the second field.Then use group by product and letter to get the counts.Filter all the products with letter 1 and finally sort it by desc order and get the top record to get the product with the highest 1 count.

```
A = LOAD 'product_details.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS(col1:int,col2:chararray,col3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE col1,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(col2,'|')) AS letter;
C = GROUP B BY (col1,letter);
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (product,letter),COUNT(B.letter) as total;
E = FILTER D BY (letter == '1');
F = ORDER E BY total DESC;
G = LIMIT F 1;
DUMP G;
```

**Output**

[image]